# How can I select all programs from the table where Term == Fall 2020, and sum all the values of the column? I use Linq in MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

[Table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMbDn.png)

Please view the table image.
How can I select all programs from the table where Term == Fall 2020,from column == "Applied" and sum all the values of the column?
Thank you in advance!
Below is the Model that generate the table

```
public partial class MAJOR_STATUS_COUNT
{
    [StringLength(47)]
    public string TERM { get; set; }

    [StringLength(40)]
    public string MAJOR { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string ACCEPTED { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string CANCELED { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string APPLIED { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string PROSPECT { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string DENIED { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string ENROLLED { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string GET_DATE { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string TOTAL { get; set; }

    public int MAJOR_STATUS_COUNTId { get; set; }

}
```

}

and below is the ActionResult that display the table in the image

```
public ActionResult GetMajorStatusCount()
    {
        var majorStatusCount = from m in db.MAJOR_STATUS_COUNT
                               .OrderBy(m => m.MAJOR)
                               select m;


       return View(majorStatusCount);

    }
```

Comment: may be you search this : `int sum = (from m in db.MAJOR_STATUS_COUNT where m == "Fall 2020" select m).Sum(x=>x.APPLIED)`

Comment: where m == "Fall 2020" gave me an error. so I tried this int sum = (from m in db.MAJOR_STATUS_COUNT
                       .Where(m => m.TERM == "Fall 2020")
                           select m)
                       .Sum(x => int.Parse(x.APPLIED)); but the Applied datatype is string. int.Parse is not working for me neither

Comment: @Saranya you're welcome!, my bad :), it's ``where m.TERM  == "Fall 2020" ``. if you don't tag me like (@sajid), i can't receive your message.

Comment: @sajid thanks , that error is gone! but I try to convert string type of the Applied value to int. this is a new error for me. But it is the improvement!

Comment: @sajid  my database developer just changed the datatype from string to int for me from the database! so now I can try your code out! thanks again